# why the value of onReadRemoteRssi() callback is 0?

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I put the **mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();** in to mGattCallback.

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
            int newState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String intentAction;
        if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
```

And also put the **onReadRemoteRssi** in **BluetoothGattCallback function**

```
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }

        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            final Intent rssiIntent = new Intent(BluetoothLeService.this, DeviceControl.class);
            rssiIntent.putExtra(DeviceControl.RSSI, rssi);
        }


        };//BluetoothGattCallback End
```

It will call the readRemoteRssi() and onReadRemoteRssi(), but I don't know why the rssi is 0...

The log look like:

```
D/BluetoothGatt( 3684): readRssi() - device: 90:59:AF:0B:8A:AB
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2463): readRemoteRssi() - address=90:59:AF:0B:8A:AB
    　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
    　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
    　　　　　　    　　　　　　．
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2463): onReadRemoteRssi() - clientIf=4 address=90:59:AF:0B:8A:AB, rssi=0, status=0
D/BluetoothGatt( 3684): onReadRemoteRssi() - Device=90:59:AF:0B:8A:AB rssi=0 status=0
```

I am sure my BLE device is normal.
But I don't know why the rssi value is o??

Can someone teach me??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the BT controller, a value of `0` might mean that the RSSI is within the *"Golden Receive Power Range"*.  If the value is negative, it means it is less than -60 dB and if the value is positive it is above -40 dB.

This is true for the low level call `HCI_Read_RSSI()` in the Bluetopia stack. I'm not sure if this applies to your case.

See the end of this post here: http://www.palowireless.com/infotooth/tutorial/radio.asp where it discusses RSSI.

Try increasing the range of your BLE devices so that the RSSI drops out of the golden range, and maybe you will get non zero values.

Comment: Link is dead but you can check it in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130530150927/http://www.palowireless.com/infotooth/tutorial/radio.asp

Answer (score 1):

I believe the RSSI scale in this case runs from -100 to 0, with 0 being the strongest. Try moving your bluetooth device further away and see if you get a nonzero number.